# Regex forces star to give at least one character, while it should be none

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a Regex for a custom syntax file to use in Sublime Text 2, made with YAML. My syntax has commands in this form, with a maximum of 6 arguments:

```
#MY_COMMAND.argument01.argument02 with spaces and characters.arg03#
```

I want to color the command name, dots, and arguments all in different colors, so I want a Regex that selects all the contents in different groups, so I can use captures to color them in the YAML file.

I came up with this one:

```
/([^.]*)(.)([^.]*)(.)([^.]*)(.)([^.]*)(.)([^.]*)(.)([^.]*)(?=#)/
```

It does almost exactly what I want. It works great as long as the command has the maximum of arguments, which is 6, and just as much as how many times I wrote `([^.]*)`.

So this works fine. But when I use less arguments, something weird (and to me, unexpected) happens. The last few groups, that should just return nothing at all, each grab a single character on the end of the string, which makes the last argument have a few less characters than intended.

Apparently I can't share images yet, because I just made this account, but you can check out the problem [here](http://regexr.com/3bmmh). In this example, you can hover over the text to see the groups. In this case, I would like group 7 to contain `foo` and I would like group 8 and up to contain nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should escape dots in the pattern to match literal dots (if `(.)` is meant to match a literal dot). Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB6kY3/2) - are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Your demo does not match anything as long as the number of arguments is less than 6. What I want is that the regex still matches, but just stops at the # no matter how many arguments there were (as long as it's less than 7)

Comment: The escaped dot is new to me though, so thanks for that, because indeed I only wanted to match a literal dot.

Comment: Something like [`/^([^.]*)(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?=#)/m`](https://regex101.com/r/rB6kY3/3)? (in multiline mode, you can also have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB6kY3/4)).

Comment: That looks way better! Thanks dude! Do you have any idea why some lengths cause the # to be contained in the match? That's not supposed to happen.

Comment: Could you please show which string exactly? If my suggestion works I will post it.

Comment: Nevermind! When I use it in single lines (which I intend to do) it works like a charm. You can write this as the answer, or I'll do it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful when matching a literal dot with a regex: either escape it outside a character class (`\.`), or use it inside a character class (`[.]`).

To make some parts of the regex optional, use non-capturing groups with `?` quantifier.

Thus, you can use the following regex:

```
/^([^.]*)(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?:\.([^.]*))?(?=#)/m
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB6kY3/4)

Note that in multiline mode, the `[^.]` can "overmatch" across lines as it also matches newline symbol. The multiline mode makes `^` match at the beginning of a line. Perhaps, you do not need the multiline mode at all, so adjust as appropriate.